# Sending User Message From My Site To My Email In ASP.NET Core MVC 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1

I have a C# code as below in ASP.NET Core MVC 2.1 to send user message to me from my site:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> ContactSohJel(string txtEmail, string txtSubject, string txtFirstName, string txtLastName, string txtMessage)
{
    using (MailMessage message = new MailMessage())
    {
        try
        {
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            //mail.From = new MailAddress("mail@sohjel.ir");
            mail.To.Add("mail@sohjel.ir");
            mail.CC.Add("sohjelveh@gmail.com");
            mail.Bcc.Add("sohjel@yahoo.com");
            mail.From = new MailAddress(txtEmail, txtSubject, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
            mail.Subject = "Subject: " + txtSubject + " --- " + "This Message Has Been Sent From: SohJel Let's Learn English WebSite. Microsoft ASP.NET Core MVC";
            mail.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            mail.Body = "<h1>Sender</h1><br/><h2>Information:<br/></h2><h3><strong>First Name: </strong>" + txtFirstName + "<br/><strong>Last Name: </strong>" + txtLastName + "<br/><strong>Email: </strong>" + txtEmail + "<br/><strong>Subject: </strong>" + txtSubject + "<br/><h2>Message: <br/></h2><h3><textarea rows=15 cols=80>" + txtMessage + "</textarea><br/>" + "<br/>" + "<br/>" + "<br/>" + "</h3>" + "This Message Has Been Sent From: SohJel Let's Learn English WebSite.";
            mail.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            mail.Priority = MailPriority.High;
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();

            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("mail@sohjel.ir", "********");
            client.Port = **;
            //client.Port = ***;
            client.Host = "***.***.***.**";
            client.EnableSsl = false;
            await client.SendMailAsync(mail);
            TempData["testmsg"] = " Your Message Sent Successfully To Me! ";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            TempData["testmsg"] = " An Error Occured!: Your Message Was NOT Sent To Me! ";
            ViewBag.Title = ex.Message;
        }
    }
    return View("ContactSohJel");
}
```

Now my problem is message isn't sent to me!
* this code works with my gmail accout on my LOCALHOST but it doesn't work on my website!

Comment: I receive this error message from my site where is located on my host: Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: From domain must match authenticated domain

Answer (score 0):

The error seems pretty clear.  The "FROM" address domain must be the same as the authentication domain.

You are passing in, presumably, the user's email address to use in the FROM header.  That's not ok.  You should use your own address in the FROM field.